# Верстка письма

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Если нужно при верстки письма текст отделить от картинок, то есть нужно визуально добиться того что бы текст был сверху на картинке, как это сделать лучше всего, если фон использовать нельзя (или нежелательно) и текст left и top -ом  нельзя позиционировать текст поверх картинки?

*Посмотрел статьи на хабре,но в примерах там избегают, изображения с текстом, они идут вместе, и по сути являються одной картинкой.*

Comment: А можете подробнее почему нельзя использовать position:absolute? Просто интерестно почему и что это за заказ такой.

Comment: Я долго искал способ это сделать, но ничего не нашел. Верстка писем, особенно адаптивная, застряла в 2005 году, т.к. верстается только на таблицах. Не ломайте голову, и вырезайте картинки с текстом.

Answer (score 2):

Поддержка css почтовиками - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

1. Как вариант использование фонового изображения, но Outlook 2007 не дает использовать фоновые картинки. В Gmail c февраля 2016г фоновые изображения стали работать.
2. 2 вариант более надежный - это использование изображения с текстом.